# How to compute document similarity against a document collection?

Tags: information-retrieval

What could be the approaches to combine the pairwise document similarity scores to get the overall similarity score of a certain document against a document collection?

How to compute document similarity against a document collection? - ResearchGate. Available from: https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_compute_document_similarity_against_a_document_collection [accessed Aug 22, 2016].

Answer (score 0):

One way of approaching this is the way that a naive bayes text classifier works. By "concatenating" all of the documents in your collection into one large pseudo-document, you can assess the similarity of a particular document against that "collection's" document. This is how the majority of spam filters work; they compare the text of a document "cheap pharmaceuticals" against the text seen in your spam documents and see if it is more like them than the documents you tend to read.

This "pseudo-document" approach is probably the most efficient way to compute such a similarity, since you only need to do your similarity calculation once per document after you pre-compute a representation for the collection.

If you truly have a document similarity matrix and want to use document-pair similarities rather than creating a pseudo-document, you're almost performing clustering. (I say this because how to combine intra-document similarities is the subject of the different linking methods in types of clustering).

One way to do this might be to look at the average similarity. For a document, you sum up the similarity scores between that document and all other documents, and divide by the total. This would give you a sense of the average distance between that document and the others in your similarity space. An outlier would have a higher average distance since most documents are farther away from it than a document in the center of a cluster.

Without more information about your similarity measure or what problem you're trying to solve, I'm not sure I can give better advice.